# cases for SocketTimeoutException in android

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect a url using HttpURLConnection when my url is not valid then i get this error of socket timeout.

so there can be two cases

1)Host is unreachable.
2)Connection TimeOut

So does it mean this error will occur when above 2 cases will occur or is there any condition for which this error can occur.

Comment: It doesn't occur in either of those two cases. Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)  - "This exception is thrown when a timeout expired on a socket read or accept operation." You can catch both SocketTimeOutException and ConnectionTimeOutException separately.